# How can I filter excel rows where the id column has at least two rows with condition

Tags: excel

I have the following excel structure:

```
| ID | ValueCond   |     Value    |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1  |        1000 |     120      |
| 2  |        2000 |     321      |
| 3  |        1000 |     322      |
| 1  |        1000 |     121      |
| 2  |        1000 |     333      |
| 3  |        2000 |     111      |
```

I need to get all rows where an ID number has two rows at least where one has Col1 column with A value and another Col1 column with C value. Let's say the condition is getting all rows where ID has 1000 and 2000 in two different rows and gett al rows of that ID.
I just need those filters and once I get those rows, I will need to do more manipulations with a pivot table.

In the example above, I would want to get rows containing IDs 2,3 as they have rows with both 1000 and 2000 values, but not 1 as it only has 1000 in ValueCond.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this one?

Comment: create a helper column to make a filter flag. Can you expand on your sample data? 2 rows is not enough to really show how a filter should operate. It's not really clear what you want since the example you are explaining doesn't seem apply to your table. Make a table that we could actually apply your rules to OR just explain your criteria a little more...

Comment: Updated the example

Comment: And just to make sure it’s clear, what rows are you looking to target with filter? I suspect you just need a countif

Comment: I would want rows 2,3,5 and 6 as they all contain IDs 2,3. countif doesn't work on multiple rows. I need both 1000 and 2000 values in two different rows in order to take the row into consideration.

Comment: any luck on the tryout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is located in column A-C. Put this in D2 and drag downwards :

```
=IF(B2=1000,IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,2000)>=1,A2,""),"")
```

TLDR : initiate a check only when column B have 1000. Then list it out in column D.